# Do we want an [umvue] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

The [umvue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umvue) tag has one question on it. Do we want to keep it going or not?

For those of us who are not familiar with UMVUEs (uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimators), the long story short is that they are (in my opinion) the culmination of a statistical inference course when it comes to parameter estimation, particularly in graduate-level statistics. Because of this, one could argue that it should be synonymized with [parameter-estimation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parameter-estimation).

I have no strong preference for either option.

[Tag Management 2018 Post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29619/81560)

Comment: A.: No. $ $ $ $

Comment: My philosophy on tags is more "impromptu" than recent discussions of them seem to reflect.  I see no harm in allowing users to introduce new tags (given sufficient reputation) when there is a perceived need, and let them prosper or fail for the better part of a month before taking Community action to eliminate or synonymize them.  This is particularly so if the originator takes the time to write a nice Wiki and excerpt.

Comment: Not strictly relevant to our stance, but as might be expected [CrossValidated has such a tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umvue) with a few dozen Questions.  It could be used to model a Wiki here, if desired.

Comment: If there's only a dozen on CV about it I doubt we will get more here.

Comment: Some data on this site: "UMVUE" has appeared in [102 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=umvue+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: @hardmath: While I don't disagree, I also feel that this shouldn't be a reputation based privilege. Rather it should be based on experience with the tagging system, which is fragile already.

Comment: I have [pinged the tag-creator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/1/10) with a comment linking to this post - it might be useful that they know about this discussion, too.

Comment: FWIW, there was an opinion in [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20944/356647) that there are too few tags relative to the number of posts we have, compared with other sites. Please see bullet number 7. This observation was made $3.5$ years ago, and I'm not sure if it was true back then or if it's still relevant now.