# Downvoting newbie user's questions

Tags: discussion, down-votes, new-users

I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142217/there-are-two-possible-solutions-to-this-question-sqrt33-33-33) today. Yeah, I agree that this question has been asked many times before but isn't 9 downvotes for a new user a bit too intense? I think mass downvoting newbies will only harm the site long term (as per new long term users goes).

What I would suggest people to do is leave helpful comments and if OP isn't ready to fix their question, then only go for close vote rather than downvote if it's a new user.

Why? The meaning of downvote isn't something that a new user could understand without any comments pointing out what's wrong, and, the second reason would be that people are more likely to turn long term contributors if they have a good first experience where they feel welcomed.

Maybe there are reasons that I don't know on why it is a good idea to vote like this, if this is the case kindly explain why it would be as an answer.

Comment: Why do you connect the downvotes to CURED?  I myself never add a downvote after -4.  I agree that piling on downvotes serves no purpose, but don't attribute that phenomenon to CURED users.  Please be careful about pointing fingers at a rather small group of people.  I think your question is otherwise worth considering, had you started with "I encountered this question.... blah, blah"

Comment: Hmm fair, I did it because I found the question from there. However, pointing fingers will not help. So I will remove that point

Comment: I voted to close the question, for one, because it has been duplicated dozens of times, in various forms.  But I'm not out to humiliate askers.

Comment: I didn't mean this to be a question, I meant this to be a discussion(as shown with the tags)/ on something which happened because we should consider this event on how we proceed as a community.

Comment: @amWhy: There is a point, although I agree that it is a bit lost in the case of new users (not necessarily new accounts). The more downvotes are added, the faster a user account will go into rate limits and be blocked automatically. But yes, with a new user this isn't usually the intended outcome.

Comment: Yes, @Asaf, you're entirely correct on that.

Comment: The downvotes here could also be because this is an elementary question. I have pointed out many times before that people often downvote because they think the OP misses a step that they definitely(in the eyes of the downvoter) ought to have seen earlier. This happens quite often and can skew elementary questions. The only way to prevent this occuring is to judge a question as a user who is only looking at the question's worth w.r.t site rules : on the FLIP side, we have questions that get upvoted only because users feel challenged, although they are PSQs. These come under the same bracket.

Comment: [Downvoting new user's questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19434) ([linked questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/19434)),
[Quick downvoting of ill-formatted questions by new users](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4113) ([linked questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4113)),
[Can we please be more generous to elementary beginners?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30038) ([linked questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30038)), ... 
You probably can find some other similar discussions.

Comment: Maybe it would have been better if the question had been closed as a duplicate. No one has even suggested in the comments on it, a duplicate target.

Comment: Well, I was a new user at one point and I posted PSQs and I was digitally murdered for it. It was warranted. In a way I do support the tough love approach. I don't like the idea that the down-votee is totally clueless about the situation.

Comment: My opinion: for a bad question by a new user, yes: vote to close, but no: do not downvote.  For a user with reputation 1, downvotes have no effect (1 is the minimum possible rep) except to upset the user.

Comment: @GEdgar Even though downvotes in such cases don't decrease reputation, I don't think it has no effect besides upsetting the user. For example, questions whose score is below -3 gets hidden from the front page. Asaf mentioned above that it makes more likely for the downvoted user to trigger rate limits and get auto-blocked. Also if a question has a negative score and no answers, it will be automatically deleted after 30 days. Though we can still discuss if these effects are desirable when it comes to new users.

Comment: I see no sense to downvote any question if it is not obviously aimed to insult the users or otherwise to harm the site.

Comment: @user Downvotes are used to indicate that the question is not useful. What do you think : is every question useful? Are there better ways of saying a question is not useful than downvoting? Should a person not lose reputation for posting non-useful questions? Please be more precise in what you want to converse about, unless you don't wish to, in which case , each to their own. I want to converse since I disagree with you.

Comment: The question has two undelete votes on it : one is mine. I believe the question merits 
 being marked as a duplicate (of an appropriate question, I will search for one and leave a link below once I find it) and being on site, but shouldn't have been deleted. I still refer to my earlier comment vis-a-vis how downvoting based on personal preference doesn't match up with site standards-based voting, whether it's up or down votes, but here I'd like the undeletion of this question and am attempting to place it as a duplicate closure, which is a milder, more appropriate stance.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Answers can be not useful (or even harmful), not the questions, if the latter are about math. I especially pointed out that I can imagine to downvote a question which is obviously not about math.

Comment: @user Thanks. So I take it this way : every mathematical question is useful to you, is that right? While answers may or may not be useful, is that right?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I will not downvote a question only because it is useless *personally* for me (probably 90% of questions here are of this sort).

Comment: @user If downvotes aren't personal, then on whose behalf are they performed? The community shapes itself through people's personal opinions combined with the site rules, and the up and down votes must be people's reflections of how a question is judged. If you are downvoting from a site-rules point of view, then the site rules say that this question is not useful because it's a duplicate, and that it is a duplicate can be argued by the people here (it's not axiomatic, but what is axiomatic in real life?). So even if I'm representing the site and not myself I'd understand a downvote.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I would never downvote a question just because it is a duplicate. We cannot require from a user (especially a new one) to spend hours searching the archive of MSE. Moreover it will appear that in some sense almost any question is a duplicate.

Comment: @user That depends : I wrote "plus or minus sign in squaring math stack" on Google, and there's enough material to be seen there, more than 20 questions that I have already gone through that say : sign discrepancy while taking the square root. If the user hasn't gone through these posts, then there's at least one person who thinks that is a lack of effort from the user. Yes, the user's very *particular* question doesn't have a duplicate verbose : but without doubt there exist posts that address their concern and beyond.

Comment: Having said that, I think this particular post has suffered more from the elementary-downvote phenomena than the duplication issue, which was raised fairly late (but correctly) on this thread as well, so this may not be the perfect duplicate thread to discuss, and to be honest, I wouldn't have downvoted, only voted to close as a dupe for addressal in the comments. But there's enough occasions (e.g. solve $x^a = b \mod c$) where *obvious* duplicates on the site are present. We have to do something about duplication, of course.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I agree with you last comment. I think this is the appropriate action, not a downvote.

Comment: @user Correct, thanks for the agreement (I also said I'll find a dupe thread, so I'll go and look for that).

Comment: I'll often downvote and vote to close low effort questions simply because there are too many users that encourage low effort question behavior by answering them for quick points. The downvote signals that something is wrong and hopefully discourages the behavior. I don't like to do it though.

Comment: New users who ask lousy low-effort questions are often the same users who get bent out of shape in response to VTC or comments telling them what they did wrong. If I smell a chance of that happening, I'm not going to participate in an interaction that makes me a target — but I can still vote to help those people who want to find worthwhile questions to answer.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks for your opinion : if I am able to understand why you do not like to do it, perhaps I may ease your worries in this direction a little? That is, of course if you wish to rid yourself of it : sometimes the best clarity comes from reflections after periods of great confusion!

Comment: @hobbs Thanks, although some may ask for evidence of your first statement, I've seen enough to agree with you. Having said that, what happened here is slightly negative in my opinion : a new user posts a question that lacks MathJax and can be classed as a duplicate but not much else, and doesn't express disagreement in the one comment they posted or make anyone a target. I don't think the question is either lousy or low-effort (with the context of being a plus-minus confusion) Nine downvotes! I'm in complete, complete agreement with your second statement.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I don't love downvoting newish users who ask these low effort questions because of the human impact, but I prioritize the health of MSE over the feelings of a user not acting in good faith at the end of the day.

Comment: What are CURED users?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow See the [CURED chatroom here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured).

Comment: @amWhy - to be honest, I think you're a little harsh in terms of down-votes, closing questions, deleting posts, etc.

Comment: @Rohit, to be honest, I don't think you know who I am, or know enough about my work to be so judgemental  against me. Before you flood users with your uneducutated opinions of them, educate yourself.  Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

Cross-site duplicate: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

The short answer is that upvotes and downvotes are not primarily intended to be instructive for the OP - they're intended to be a signal to other readers as to whether the content is worth reading or not. If you would like to educate a new user as to how to use the site, you are, of course, free to leave a comment explaining how to improve their post.

To quote from the linked Q&A,

> Downvotes are, first and foremost, a content rating system. Rather than being a way of communicating with the poster, they are a way of communicating to future readers that a question or answer is not interesting or useful. If someone wants to leave a comment to communicate with the poster, they can always do so, independent of the voting system.

Also, one of the basic principles of site moderation is to vote on content, not users. Avoiding downvoting or voting to close a new user's question is voting on users, not content.

Comment: The principle that downvotes are about content, not users, is a good one. However, new users are likely to be unfamiliar with this, and see downvotes on their posts as a personal insult. Moreover, once the downvotes have reached a certain threshold, it is already clear to other readers that the post is low quality. What good does it do for a new user's post to be sitting at $9$ downvotes?

Comment: @Joe It's a little unclear to me how we prevent new users from taking downvotes personally. By that logic, we could never downvote any post from any new user no matter how bad. I do agree that pile-on downvotes seem a little excessive (since a score of, for example, -5 would signal that the content isn't useful just as well as -9 would), but I definitely don't agree that we should treat new users' posts any differently than we treat anyone else's (because that would be moderating users rather than content).

Comment: @Joe A case could *maybe* be made for discouraging downvoting a question beyond, say, -5 votes (to discourage pile-on downvotes), but that standard would obviously have to be applied uniformly (not just to new users).

Comment: I certainly have downvoted new users' posts. But that's when I think that the good that it does for the site in terms of filtering out bad content outweighs the discouragement that it might bring to that user. Also, I think it *is* sensible to treat new users differently. For instance, I might be forgiving if a new user for not using MathJax in their post, but I certainly wouldn't give as much leeway to an established user. I don't agree that voting should be based *solely* on the content of the post, even if that is an important aspect to it. But we can agree to disagree.

Comment: @Joe Personally, I generally don't downvote for formatting problems (unless it's so severe that it can't be fixed by editing and it renders the post unreadable, in which case it makes the question unclear). In general, if a problem can be fixed by another user editing the post, it's better to try to salvage the post than to downvote or vote to close. If the post's problems can't be fixed by anyone other than the OP editing, then downvoting and/or voting to close could be appropriate.

Comment: I get the sense that some people downvote because they think the question is "stupid" in the sense that the answer is obvious (to them) or that it is trivially answered by Googling or some other means.  As a questioner in a new subject area though, this is problematic when I have tried and can't find the answer.  More generally, there's the problem that downvotes are a noisy indicator of quality, but it only takes one or two before nobody will even look at your question anymore.